# sddm login window on two screens with different resolution

Tags: login-screen, display-resolution, sddm

I have two monitors with different resolutions (1920x1200 and 1680x1050).

When I turn on the computer, on the smaller screen I see a correct login window, but on the larger screen I see a 1920x1200 login window, plus a 1680x1050 login screen in the top left corner, superimposed.

It looks very bad and confusing. What can I do to get rid of that extra layer in the larger monitor?

Comment: I have the same problem...